# How to check which of the Object parameters got changed

Tags: java, spring

I have a situation where i am changing few parameters values of an Object.

UserDetails has around 14 parameters.I am changing the values of few parameters and submitting them from a Form .These values should get updated on the database back-end.

Are there any inbuilt functions to check if any of the values got changed?

Comment: what javascript has to do with this?

Comment: check the previous and current hashCode()

Comment: your server function should return an object with the updated values, to be a "good practice" way.. maybe is it happening now?

Comment: @SMA   ..by mistake added it.As i a coding my front-end in javascript it just came into my hands

Comment: http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Comment: Why would you do that? Just save everything. The user wants these 14 fields to have the value he chose to submit, so save the 14 fields with the 14 submitted values.

Comment: @Raghuveer  I am doing the same at present.Is there any other smartway?becausing with this i have to check for each and every parameter

Comment: @JBNizet  it is like we have created an account online to some site with some fields like personal details and stuff.Now the person wants to change only few of them like his mobile number

Comment: What kind of persistence layer are you using ? 
Hibernate for exampe has @DynamicUpdate which tells Hibernate 
to update only fields that have changed ...

 JB Nizet's question is justified ... UNLESS you have a table with a really large number of attributes or attributes like BLOB's storing large volumes of data you could just persist everything.

Comment: Either he changes only his mobile number, because the form only has one field allowing to change the mobile number, and he thus submits the mobile number only, and you save the modified mobile number, or the form also contains 13 other fields, an the user leaves them unmodified because he wants that information to be saved as is, and so you save the 14 submitted fields, because they contain what the user chose to save. Changing the first name from Paul to Paul will save Paul in the database, and the saved data will thus be correct. No need to check if something has changed.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use hashCode() to test if two objects are equal. You should use equals(). two different objects can (and will) have the same hashCode.

Comment: @JBNizet  Got the point said.I was building a web application ,came across this situation.I have coded with equals and was curious to know if i am going in a correct way or not.Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any inbuilt functions to say which of the values got changed?

No.

> Are there any inbuilt functions to check if any of the values got changed?

No.

---

However, you can implement your own methods to test these things.  An `equals` method is easy to implement, and indeed many IDEs have "wizards" to generate them.  A "what has changed" method is more complicated.  The complexity comes in how the method tells the caller what fields have changed, and how the caller can make use of this information.

Alternatively, Apache Commons provides a class called `EqualsBuilder` that uses reflection, etcetera to compare objects based on their fields.

---

I also agree with JB Nizet.  If you are doing this in an attempt to optimize database updates, you are probably wasting your time.  You are probably better off just saving the all of the fields.

Consider this.  Unless your front-end caches the old values of the fields read from the database while the user is updating the form (or not), your front end is going to have to re-query the database to find the old value.  You would be better off just issuing the UPDATE to update all of the fields than doing a SELECT followed by a conditional UPDATE is something has changed.

Comment: Note that since Java 7, implementing equals() is much easier without any additional dependency: `Objects.equals(foo.a, bar.a) && Objects.equals(foo.b, bar.b) && ...`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can check this link.. I am not sure this can be done in java. But, you can try with javascript. Please check this link. You can do with EXT.js

```
handler: function(btn, evt) {
                var f = btn.up('form').getForm();
                f.submit({
                    url: '/some-path-on-my-server/save/,
                    getParams: function(useModelValues) {
                        var falseVal = false;
                        var fieldParams = this.form.getValues(falseVal, true, this.submitEmptyText !== falseVal, useModelValues,  true);
                        return Ext.apply({}, fieldParams);
                    }
                });
            }
```

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?173867-I-want-to-submit-only-dirty-field-values.